# Binding WPF button contained in a usercontrol, with its own viewmodel, to a function in the mainwindow viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a simple window with a UserControl inside of it "NewCardView". The cancel button needs to call a function contained in the MainWindow's view model in order to switch the currently displayed UserControl. When I press the button it does nothing, nothing to trace, like it isn't bound to anything. I have tried binding to the datacontext of that window but I have been unsuccessful.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MapProject.View.NewCardView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MapProject.MainView.View"
                 xmlns:mainwin="clr-namespace:MapProject"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="labeltitle" Content="New Card" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="133,43,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,74,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="133,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="133,136,0,0" Width="120"/>
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="District" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,43,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Map #" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,74,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Parcel #" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,105,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Date From" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="62,136,0,0"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Cancel" CommandParameter="Blank" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mainwin:MainWindow}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

        </Grid>
```

```
    public ICommand ChangePageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changePageCommand == null)
            {
                _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(p => ChangeViewModel(p.ToString()), p => p is string);
            }

            return _changePageCommand;
        }
```

### }

MainWindow contains this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mainviewviewmodel:NewCardViewModel}">
    <mainview:NewCardView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

    namespace MapProject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A command whose sole purpose is to 
        /// relay its functionality to other
        /// objects by invoking delegates. The
        /// default return value for the CanExecute
        /// method is 'true'.
        /// </summary>
        public class RelayCommand : ICommand
        {
            #region Fields

            readonly Action<object> _execute;
            readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

            #endregion // Fields

            #region Constructors

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
            public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
                : this(execute, null)
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a new command.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
            /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
            public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
            {
                if (execute == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

                _execute = execute;
                _canExecute = canExecute;
            }

            #endregion // Constructors

            #region ICommand Members

            [DebuggerStepThrough]
            public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
            {
                return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
            }

            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
            {
                add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
                remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
            }

            public void Execute(object parameters)
            {
                _execute(parameters);
            }

            #endregion // ICommand Members
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although you say "UserControl with its own view model", your code doesn't look like the UserControl would actually have an own view model. And it shouldn't have one anyway. So the Command Binding could simply be `Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}"`. As a note, setting BindsDirectlyToSource has no effect unless you bind to a DataSourceProvider.

Comment: I have added what I believe is the assignment contained in the MainSearch. I have tried your suggestion but I believe it is in a different datacontext when I assign that. Could you explain why it shouldn't have its own view model?

Comment: The ChangePageCommand should be in NewCardViewModel.

Comment: But then how would it communicate with my main window? The object that controls which usercontrol is being displayed is located in that viewmodel. I roughly followed this tutorial : [link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: ChangePageCommand is a property in NewCardViewModel, but could be set by the MainViewModel and hence execute a method in the MainViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Clemens correctly suggested, the best solution is to leave the **ChangePageCommand** command at the **NewCardViewModel** level. When creating NewCardViewModel, initialize the ChangePageCommand command so that it calls a **method from MainViewModel**:

```
public class MainViewModel {
    public void CreateNewCard() {
        NewCardViewModel newCardModel = new NewCardViewModel();
        newCardModel.ChangePageCommand = new RelyCommand(Cancel);
        //...
    }
    void Cancel() {

    }
}

public class NewCardViewModel {
    public ICommand ChangePageCommand {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In this case, the following simple binding should properly work:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" ... />
```

If you don't wish to initialize NewCardViewModel in MainViewModel this way, you can use a [free DevExpress MVVM Framework](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExpress.Mvvm.Free) for making child view models [aware of their parents](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17449).

Another solution available with the same MVVM framework is to use [Messenger](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17474) to communicate between different view models. With this approach, you can register an action at the MainViewModel level and invoke it from NewCardViewModel without creating any strong dependencies or even interfaces.

Comment: This was able to accomplish what I needed, much appreciated. I have a much better understanding.